# Spinner(CircularProgress) before function starts using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make something like this.

onClick --> post_query() starts --> spinner() shows --> post_query() ends --> modal shows

The problem I have is that spinner is showing before post_query() starts.
And I think it's because  state loading is true( const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); )

How can I make the spinner start after the post_query() start? (I tried using useEffect() but failed to handle with useEffect)

```
function Header() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  const modal_open = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  const modal_close = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  const post_query = (e) => {

      var result = new Map()
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/' + query)
      .then(function(response){
        var content=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).data
        for (var i=0;i<content.data.length;i++){
          result.set(content.data[i].image_id, content.data[i].caption)
        }

        var key = Array.from(result.keys());
        setKeys(key);    

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("error");
        alert(err);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false)); 
    };
   


  return (
    <div className="header">
      <Link to="/">
        <img
          src="logo.png"
          className="header__logo"
        />
      </Link>
      <div className="header__search">
        <input className="header__searchInput" type="search" 
        onChange={
          (e) => {
            setQuery(e.target.value);
          }
        }/>
        <SearchIcon className="header__searchIcon" 
        onClick={(e)=> { post_query(); modal_open();}}/>
        
        {loading && <div><CircularProgress className="spinner"/></div>}
        
        {!loading && 
         <Modal 
            open={isOpen}
            onClose={modal_close} >
        
      <Fade in={isOpen}>
            <div className='modal_frame'>
              <img src={'img'+keys[0]+'.jpg'} className='modal_img' />
            </div>
       </Fade>
       </Modal>
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Have your initial loading state as false . and move this `setLoading(true)` inside your `post_query` function above the axios call .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `setLoading` to true when call `post_query` and change initail value to `false`

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const post_query = (e) => {
  var result = new Map()
  setLoading(true)
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/' + query)
  ...
};
```